# Как открывать гиперссылку не в новой вкладке, а в той же? HTML

Tags: html, button

я новичок. Разрабатываю сайт портфолио. Имеется кнопка с переходом на другую страницу через гиперссылку, которая открывается в новой вкладке. Как сделать чтобы она открывалась в той же самой вкладке, а не в новой? Вот отрывок из кода:

```
<form action="contactme.html" target="_blank">
<button>Связаться со мной</button>
</form>
<br>
```

Comment: Убрать [`target="_blank"`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/target)

Answer (score 2):

```html
<form action="contactme.html">
    <button>Связаться со мной</button>
</form>

<br>
```